# Post large DataUri to another server with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, http-post, data-uri

I have a string contains image dataUri. I need to post this string to ANOTHER remote server, so I use the form and iframe technique to do that.

The problem is, that when the string is too  large (the image is too big) - the server doesn't accept it. That means, the string shows up 'null' on the server. 
I've read a lot about this issue on SO, and all the answers relies on Bolb objects in this way or another. Unfortunately, IE9 doesn't support it.

Is there anyway to pass a (VERY) large string from the client to the server? multipart post doesn't work either, since (as I understand) it works only for files, not parameters.

Comment: How big are they? From your comments, I'm to assume you require IE support (IE10 isn't too far from reality). So. Web sockets are out? Is that what you were referencing in the Blob problem? If you can't use something like [Comet with HTML5 web sockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/) asynchronously, then would it be possible to chunk your DataUri data and feed it one chunk at a time until it's all been fed through a POST op?

Comment: do send it as a post param, or part of the url? urls are more limited in length. otherwise, just reconfigure your webserver to raise the limit on post size.

Comment: I put the dataUri as a value of a hidden input, then do something like 'myForm.append(myInput); myForm.submit()'. 
The server fails to accept the value if the string is bigger then 200K chars, or something like that. For shorter strings (smaller images) it works great. 
When fails, IE debbuger shows 'aborted' on the 'Result' column, on the Network page.

Comment: if it fails in all browsers, reconfigure your webserver.

Comment: btw a warning. I would split it into multiple hidden fields because some browsers will truncate the individual length(chrome truncates around half a million bytes).